# How to filter out earliest and latest datetime in column by group?

Tags: r, date, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

I feel like this is a basic question, but I have looked around at questions on SO that involved filtering a column of dates, but have only found questions where it's only the earliest or the latest (and not both in my case).

I have a longitudinal dataframe, `df2` of cortical measurements (`M1`), subject IDs (`SubjID`), and dates (`SeshLab`), as seen below (this is just a dummy dataframe)

```
SubjID     SeshLab        M1
123456     2010-12-03     7.89
123456     2011-06-03     7.65
123456     2011-12-03     6.54
135791     2010-12-03     7.91
135791     2011-06-03     7.53
```

I have tried a `filter` command but I get a vector related error saying that the input cannot be of type variable.

```
> df3 <- df2 %>%
+   group_by(SubjID) %>%
+   filter(n()>1) %>%
+   filter(min(SeshLab), max(SeshLab))
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a date.
ℹ Input `..1` is `min(SeshLab)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: SubjID = "123456".
```

I have done `summarise` but I also can't seem to find a way to keep the cortical measurments intact with it.

```
> View(df3)
> df3 <- df2 %>%
+ group_by(SubjID) %>%
+ summarise(visitmin = min(SeshLab), visitmax = max(SeshLab))

SubjID     visitmin       visitmax
123456     2010-12-03     2011-12-03
135791     2010-12-03     2011-06-03
```

The goal is to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
SubjID     SeshLab        M1
123456     2010-12-03     7.89
123456     2011-12-03     6.54
135791     2010-12-03     7.91
135791     2011-06-03     7.53
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your title "filter out" suggests you want to remove these rows, but I think you want to  keep them?

Answer (score 3):

We can use an OR (`|`) condition to `filter` by `min` or `max` `SeshLab`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(SeshLab = as.Date(SeshLab)) %>%
  group_by(SubjID) %>%
  filter(SeshLab == min(SeshLab) | SeshLab == max(SeshLab))
  #We can also use range
  #filter(SeshLab %in% range(SeshLab)) %>%
  ungroup

#  SubjID SeshLab       M1
#   <int> <date>     <dbl>
#1 123456 2010-12-03  7.89
#2 123456 2011-12-03  6.54
#3 135791 2010-12-03  7.91
#4 135791 2011-06-03  7.53
```

Another way would to `arrange` the data and select 1st and last row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(SeshLab = as.Date(SeshLab)) %>%
  arrange(SubjID, SeshLab) %>%
  group_by(SubjID) %>%
  slice(1, n()) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = "SeshLab")[, .SD[c(1,.N)], by = .(SubjID)]
#    SubjID    SeshLab   M1
# 1: 123456 2010-12-03 7.89
# 2: 123456 2011-12-03 6.54
# 3: 135791 2010-12-03 7.91
# 4: 135791 2011-06-03 7.53
```